# Display/return last 12 and 24 months with year from current month and year using python (Creating Date range)

Tags: python, pandas

```
today = pd.to_datetime('today').strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
last = (pd.to_datetime(today) - pd.DateOffset(years=1)).strftime("%d/%m/%Y")

listofmonths = pd.date_range(start=last, end=today, freq='MS') 
listofmonths


Result / Output:

DatetimeIndex(['2021-06-01', '2021-07-01', '2021-08-01', '2021-09-01',
               '2021-10-01', '2021-11-01', '2021-12-01', '2022-01-01',
               '2022-02-01', '2022-03-01', '2022-04-01', '2022-05-01'],
                dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='MS')
```

Question:

Here i got **first date of the month** but along with first date i want **last date of the month**
as well. So how it will be possible.
**What change should i make to get the last date of the month as well?**

Comment: I want to go with both the options if you will help in both ways it will be easy for me to understand both the ways. mainly it should be separate index [0] for first date and [1] for last date of month

Comment: Yeah I figured you would like both, see my answer if it solves your issue!

Comment: single list will be okay but i want first and last dates in the single tuple so how to do that? 
let say ('2021-06-30', '2021-07-31') , ( '2021-08-31', '2021-09-30'),... 
i want like this

Comment: But those are all last dates no? Did you mean (2021-06-01, 2021-06-30), (2021-07-01, 2021-07-31) ? Or really ('2021-06-30', '2021-07-31')?

Comment: i want  both the dates in string only  ('2021-06-30', '2021-07-31') and  single tuple. And what changes do i have to  make in the existing code ?

Comment: I edited my answer, added an example at the end. Check if that's what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ge the end of the months you can do:

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import MonthEnd

month_ends = listofmonths + MonthEnd(1)

print(month_ends)
```

```
DatetimeIndex(['2021-06-30', '2021-07-31', '2021-08-31', '2021-09-30',
               '2021-10-31', '2021-11-30', '2021-12-31', '2022-01-31',
               '2022-02-28', '2022-03-31', '2022-04-30', '2022-05-31'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

If you want a single index:

```
joined_index = listofmonths.union(month_ends)

print(joined_index)
```

```
DatetimeIndex(['2021-06-01', '2021-06-30', '2021-07-01', '2021-07-31',
               '2021-08-01', '2021-08-31', '2021-09-01', '2021-09-30',
               '2021-10-01', '2021-10-31', '2021-11-01', '2021-11-30',
               '2021-12-01', '2021-12-31', '2022-01-01', '2022-01-31',
               '2022-02-01', '2022-02-28', '2022-03-01', '2022-03-31',
               '2022-04-01', '2022-04-30', '2022-05-01', '2022-05-31'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

### EDIT - after discussion in the comments:

To get the string tuples you can do:

```
month_tuples = list(zip(listofmonths.astype(str), month_ends.astype(str)))
print(month_tuples)
```

```
[('2021-06-01', '2021-06-30'), ('2021-07-01', '2021-07-31'), 
('2021-08-01', '2021-08-31'), ('2021-09-01', '2021-09-30'), 
('2021-10-01', '2021-10-31'), ('2021-11-01', '2021-11-30'), 
('2021-12-01', '2021-12-31'), ('2022-01-01', '2022-01-31'), 
('2022-02-01', '2022-02-28'), ('2022-03-01', '2022-03-31'), 
('2022-04-01', '2022-04-30'), ('2022-05-01', '2022-05-31')]
```

Comment: i want every month first and last date in the single tuple , " month_ends_tuples " is showing only last date of the month. So can we make it like it should show first and last date of every single months single tuples

Comment: @VedantRawal like this? See my edit.